# How can I keep the focus menu open when clicking on an anchor link inside that menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css

1. On focus, a small menu opens.
2. Clicking on a link inside a menu should not close it.
3. Clicking outside the menu area should close the menu. Just like losing focus.

Is it possible with CSS? Or a little vanilla JS.

```css
[tabindex="1"] {display:inline-block;}   
b {cursor:pointer;}
.menu {
  position:absolute; visibility:hidden;
  display:block; padding:10px; white-space:nowrap; 
  border:1px solid black; background:pink;
  transition:0.35s ease-out;
  }
[tabindex="1"]:focus .menu  {visibility:visible;}  
p:target {background:gold;}
```

```html
<div tabindex="1"><b>&#9776;</b>
  <div class="menu">
    <a href="#01">link 1</a> some text<br>
    some <a href="#02">link 2</a> text 
  </div>
</div>

<br><br><br><br><br>
<p id="01">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ..</p>
<p id="02">In lobortis nisl ac nisi tempor pulvinar..</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

what about something like this?

```
document.querySelector('[tabindex="1"]').addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.querySelector('.menu').classList.add('active')
})
```

do the same when clicking out side and just remove the active class, also change your CSS to be something like this

```
.menu.active  {visibility:visible;}
```

outside click:

```
document.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (!target.closest('.menu')) {
    document.querySelector('.menu').classList.remove('active')
  }
})
```

Comment: Not really. The third condition is not met. The menu remains open all the time.

Comment: you need to make another event handler that handles outside click, or basically anything that's not inside .menu

Comment: @Arsen check update

Comment: Checked. If you click on link 2 first, the menu will close.

Comment: @Arsen a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/eam0fqnb/

Comment: Thanks, I looked. Clicking on link 2 hides the menu. It shouldn't be.

Comment: @Arsen oh the selector was wrong, here's the updated one https://jsfiddle.net/h4x76okr/

Comment: Good. But the code doesn't work in IE 11.0. It turns out already a lot of code JS. Is there a solution for css?

Comment: @Arsen you can do something like this, but you will have to reclick the burger icon to close the menu https://jsfiddle.net/brmjLsna/

Comment: Thank you. Not bad. But a little not what you need.

Answer (score 0):

So far I'm using this solution. With javascript. Works in IE 11.0. If anyone finds a solution with initial conditions, without using javascript, please let me know.

```js
var ddc = document.querySelector(".drop");
var lnk = document.querySelectorAll("[href*='#']");

for (var i = 0; i < lnk.length; i++) {
  lnk[i].addEventListener("blur", function () {
    ddc.focus();
  });
}
```

```css
.drop {display:inline-block; position:relative; outline:none;}   
b {cursor:pointer; font-size:18px; display:inline-block; width:20px;}
.menu {
  visibility:hidden; opacity:0; position:absolute; 
  top:120%; padding:10px; white-space:nowrap; 
  border:1px solid black; background:pink;
  transition:0.55s ease-out;
  }
.drop:focus .menu  {visibility:visible; opacity:1;}  
p:target {background:gold;}

b::before, b::after {
  position:absolute; top:0; left:0; 
  line-height:1.0; transition:0.55s ease-out;
  }
b::before  {content: "\2630";}
b::after   {content: "\2715"; visibility:hidden; opacity:0;}

.drop:focus b::before {visibility:hidden; opacity:0; transform:rotateZ(180deg);}
.drop:focus b::after  {visibility:visible; opacity:1;}

i {
  position:absolute; cursor:pointer;
  top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0;
  z-index:10; opacity:0; display:none; 
}
.drop:focus i {display:inline-block;}
.drop i:focus .menu {visibility:hidden; opacity:0;}
```

```html
<div tabindex="1" class="drop">
 <i tabindex="1"></i><b></b>
  <div class="menu">
    <a href="#01">link 1</a> some text<br>
    some <a href="#02">link 2</a> text 
  </div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<p id="01">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ..</p>
<p id="02">In lobortis nisl ac nisi tempor pulvinar..</p>
```